# Code works on Jupyter Notebook but not as as .py script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Simplified example of my code, please ignore syntax errors:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymysql.cursors
from datetime import date, datetime

connection = pymysql.connect(host=,
                             user=,
                             password=,
                             db=,
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
df1 = pd.read_sql()
df2 = pd.read_sql(
df3 = pd.read_sql()

np.where(a=1, b, c)

df1.append([df2, d3])

path = r'C:\Users\\'
df.to_csv(path+'a.csv')
```

On Jupyter Notebook it outputs the csv file like it supposed to. However, it I download the .py and run with python. It will only output a csv the first time I run it after restarting my computer. Other times it will just run and nothing happens. Why this is happening is blowing my mind.

Comment: ```df.to_csv(path+'\a.csv')```

Comment: sorry, please ignore the code it self. I just post it as an example of what I'm doing. The actual code works fine on jupyter every time

Comment: I think you need to put what you are doing to know exactly what could be happening

Comment: @Totoro Sorry I can't do that, but it's just a more complicated version of my example with credentials.. What's bothering me is why it only works after restarting me computer, not the code itself.

Comment: Please at least provide information about what exactly does not work. Any error messages maybe?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch That's the problem. No error code no nothing. Works perfectly fine on Jupyter. But once downloaded as .py, it will only run the first time after system restart.

Comment: What do you mean by "not work" then? You call `python [file].py` on the command line and the program immediately returns with no output? If so, have you tried simple `print("I reached this point")`-statements to check if it actually gets executed?

Comment: What I mean is I have the exact code copy and pasted on Jupiter Notebook and .py. On the Jupiter Notebook it runs and when completed, outputs a csv file. However, on .py it runs and doesn't output anything. However, the exact same code with a different database works on both everytime.

Comment: I would check if you are using the same python env running notebook and .py file. Also add a lot of print statements and check for empty catch statements.

Comment: put a try: (your code lines here) except Exception as e: print(e)  to try to capture the error and print it. I see someone put that as an answer try that

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added the path wrongly

If you change your path to `df.to_csv(path+'\a.csv')` then it will be correct

Comment: sorry, please ignore the code it self. I just post it as an example of what I'm doing. The actual code works fine on jupyter every time. I just don't know why it's working on Jupyer but not .py

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing what your actual code is, but one thought is that the connection you have to your DB is never closed, and is somehow locking the DB so you are unable to make another connection.

The first connection would end, of course, when you restart your computer.

To see if this is an issue, you could use the MySQL command `SHOW PROCESSLIST` that would list out the different connections for you; if, after running the script the first time, one of the processes is still the same connection from your machine you just made, that could be the issue. Here's the docs on the command: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html

Alternatively, you could wrap the DB connection code in a try/except block with some print statements for good measure, to ascertain whether or not that's an issue, like so:

```
try:
    print "Right before connection"
    connection = pymysql.connect(host=,
                                 user=,
                                 password=,
                                 db=,
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    print "Right after connection"
except Exception as e:
    print "The Exception is:{}".format(str(e))
```

Also, you should most definitely print the objects that you're trying to write to CSV, to see if they're still valid the second time around (i.e. make sure you've actually populated those variables and they're not just Nones)